# Getting an error "found conflicting getters" when trying to upload a message to a firebase database

Tags: java, class, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this library: https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit to add chat to my app, i am getting this error when i try to upload a message to the firestore db:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: neoncore.com.onepiece, PID: 3907
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getUser on class neoncore.com.onepiece.beans.chat.Message
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb.zzg(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb.zzbw(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zzcd(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.add(Unknown Source)
                      at neoncore.com.onepiece.activities.ChatDetail$1.onSubmit(ChatDetail.java:57)
                      at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.onSubmit(MessageInput.java:145)
                      at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.onClick(MessageInput.java:108)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

This is my updated message class:

```
public class Message implements IMessage,
        MessageContentType.Image, /*this is for default image messages implementation*/
        MessageContentType /*and this one is for custom content type (in this case - voice message)*/ {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private Date createdAt;
    private User user;
    private Image image;
    private Voice voice;

    public Message(String id, User user, String text) {
        this(id, user, text, new Date());
    }

    public Message(String id, User user, String text, Date createdAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.user = user;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return image == null ? null : image.url;
    }

    public Voice getVoice() {
        return voice;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return "Sent";
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setVoice(Voice voice) {
        this.voice = voice;
    }

    public static class Image {

        private String url;

        public Image(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }

    public static class Voice {

        private String url;
        private int duration;

        public Voice(String url, int duration) {
            this.url = url;
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public int getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }
    }
}
```

and also my user class:

```
     [public class User implements IUser {


    private String id, name, avatar;

    public User(String id, String name, String avatar) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public User() {
    }


    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }
}][1]
```

this is the point where the error occurs:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final Author author = new Author(currentUser.getUid(),currentUser.getDisplayName(),currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
        messageMessagesListAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter<>(author.getId(),null);
        messagesList = findViewById(R.id.messagesList);


        inputView = findViewById(R.id.input);
        inputView.setInputListener(new MessageInput.InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSubmit(CharSequence input) {
                CollectionReference reference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Messages");
                final Message message = new Message(author,input.toString(), "",null,new Date());
                reference.add(message).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {

                        messageMessagesListAdapter.addToStart(message,true);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("MessageUPloadFailed",e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });

        messagesList.setAdapter(messageMessagesListAdapter);
    }
```

The error occurs at the point where i try to add the message to the firestore database where the add method is called.
 [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmFhT.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have the `@Override` annotations on your getter methods?

Comment: Implementing interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getUser on class Message
```

Because in `Message` class you have a `getUser()` method but you don't have a `user` field at all. You have instead an `author` field and the getter for this field should be:

```
@Override
public Author getAuthor() { //NOT getUser()
    return author;
}
```

Comment: You answer makes total sense, but I am still getting the same error, I changed the author class name to User and the field name also to user but I an still getting the same error

Comment: You are still getting the same error because most likely you have the same data in your database. Delete the old data, add fresh data and try again. Does it work?

Comment: I have cleared out my db in firebase..i am still getting the same error..

Comment: Please show me your changed database and your updated code to see more clearly. You can simply edit your question.

Comment: i have updated the code and also an image of the database

Comment: The error from your code is related to your `Message` class but I see in your image `Users` collection. In this collection all the properties are correct.

Comment: I am uploading the message to a new messages collection...i removed the messages collection so the query could create it again and add the message...the properties in the users collection is correct...

Comment: I don't get it. You said, `i am still getting the same error`. Tell me, what is the problem now.

Comment: The same error log i posted earlier.."found conflicting getters for name getUser"

Comment: Make your `User` class implement `Serializable`. Your `Message` contains a `User`, which is a class that Firebase won't be able to serialize/deserialize. That's why you need to implement `Serializable`. Does it work now?

Comment: not working....thanks alot for your time, i would try a different approach

Comment: What was the error? What was happening? You are close.

Comment: Still says i have conflicting getters for name getUser.. I think its an issue with the chatkit library...

Comment: If you have objects nested within other objects, you need to implement `Serializable` to all of them. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: The library has provided some interfaces that i have to implement for my model classes, so maybe that is causing some conflicts for firebase...i really dont know..

Comment: Yh..i did..u mentioned it some time ago...and i did that

Comment: There's a user class in firebase ui with the same getters, I think that's what is conflicting with my own class

Comment: That's a possibility. Try to change the name of you field and change also the getters and setters, remove the data from the database, add fresh data and try again. Does it work?

Comment: i cant change the names of my getters because i have to override them from the interface i have to implement for my model class.

Comment: Hi again..on a different note, how would you suggest I go about implementing multiple viewholders on a firestore recycler adapter.

Comment: I have created a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) in which i have explained step by step how to use ViewHolders with Firestore. Ho ahead and take a look.

Comment: Thank you...but what if i what to create two viewholders, do i have to override getitemview method..i want to create a chat recycler view with two different layouts for sent and received messages...

Comment: It depends on the use-case of your app. You can use both approaches.

Comment: hello again, i have tried implementing the adapter but i am running into this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937069/getitem-method-in-firestore-recycler-adapter-returning-null